# NODEJS Object Value Is a Key Value Pair

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webhooks, key-value

I have a request I receive through a webhook which returns the following object as req.body:

```
{"appId":"7HPEPVBTZGDCP","merchants":{"6RDH804A896K1":[{"objectId":"O9FN4R9BMKXQ0","type":"UPDATE","ts":1686754357822},{"objectId":"OE87DT9330H7R","type":"UPDATE","ts":1686754358007}]}}
```

The issue i am having is although I can access the merchants through req.body.merchants, that is a key/value pair with the key being a string and the value being an array as:

```
{"6RDH804A896K1":[{"objectId":"O9FN4R9BMKXQ0","type":"UPDATE","ts":1686754357822},{"objectId":"OE87DT9330H7R","type":"UPDATE","ts":1686754358007}]}
```

The issue i am having is that I need a way to access the key of merchants, `6RD8H04A896K1`, as well as the value which is:

```
[{"objectId":"O9FN4R9BMKXQ0","type":"UPDATE","ts":1686754357822},{"objectId":"OE87DT9330H7R","type":"UPDATE","ts":1686754358007}]
```

I tried the following but had no luck:

```
        const merchantResponse: { id : value} = req.body.merchants;
```

but that doesn't seem to work either. Can someone tell me how I can convert this nested key/value pair into a json object and access its values? The issue is I do not have the object key otherwise I could have just called it as:

```
const merchantResponse = req.body['6RDH804A896K1'];
```

anyone have a solutions to this problem?

Comment: `Object.values(req.body.merchants)[0]`

Answer (score 4):

If you need to get the `merchants`, you know you need to grab it by that key at the very least.

Just get the object values and access the first value.

```js
const req = {
  body: {
    "appId": "7HPEPVBTZGDCP",
    "merchants": {
      "6RDH804A896K1": [{
        "objectId": "O9FN4R9BMKXQ0",
        "type": "UPDATE",
        "ts": 1686754357822
      }, {
        "objectId": "OE87DT9330H7R",
        "type": "UPDATE",
        "ts": 1686754358007
      }]
    }
  }
}

const getNestedData = (root, key) => ({ [key]: Object.values(root[key])[0] });

console.log(getNestedData(req.body, 'merchants'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

### TypeScript approach

If you are doing this in TypeScript, you can try:

```
const req = {
  body: {
    "appId": "7HPEPVBTZGDCP",
    "merchants": {
      "6RDH804A896K1": [{
        "objectId": "O9FN4R9BMKXQ0",
        "type": "UPDATE",
        "ts": 1686754357822
      }, {
        "objectId": "OE87DT9330H7R",
        "type": "UPDATE",
        "ts": 1686754358007
      }]
    }
  }
};

type UpdateType = 'CREATE' | 'DELETE' | 'UPDATE';

interface Merchant {
  objectId: string,
  type: UpdateType,
  ts: number
};

function unwrapMerchants(root: object): Merchant[] {
  return Object.values(root)[0] as Merchant[];
}

const pair = { merchants: unwrapMerchants(req.body.merchants) };

console.log(pair);
```

---

After seeing your answer to your question, you can just pop the first entry off of the entries and destructure they key-value pair into variables like so:

```js
const req = {
  body: {
    "appId": "7HPEPVBTZGDCP",
    "merchants": {
      "6RDH804A896K1": [{
        "objectId": "O9FN4R9BMKXQ0",
        "type": "UPDATE",
        "ts": 1686754357822
      }, {
        "objectId": "OE87DT9330H7R",
        "type": "UPDATE",
        "ts": 1686754358007
      }]
    }
  }
}
const [merchantId, response] = Object.entries(req.body.merchants).pop();

console.log({ merchantId, response });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Safe version with optional chaining and guards:

```js
const [merchantId, response] = Object.entries(req?.body?.merchants ?? {})?.pop() ?? [];
```

Comment: so there in now way of accessing it without knowing the key value?

Comment: @z123 Which key?

Comment: the value I am trying to access is 6RDH804A896K1 in the code above.

Comment: @z123 added more info at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, there is a way to get the value of a key/value pair without knowing the key and that is by converting it to an array first. Probably not the best but the following was my workaround.

```
const notify = req.body;
    let merchantId = Object.entries(notify.merchants)[0][0];
    let response = Object.entries(notify.merchants)[0][1]
```

That sets the merchantId as `"6RDH804A896K1", which is what I was trying to do.